# Wait until Click event in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

my goal is to create an activity in Journey Builder which waits for an interaction of the user in the mail and sends a reply mail depending on what button the user clicked on.

The thing is, there shouldn't be a specific waittime after which it is checked if one of the buttons was clicked - as mentioned the reply mail should be triggered asap after the user interaction. So a click activity split would not work in this scenario.

A regular  decision split obviously wouldn't work as well.

Intuitively the wait until event acitivity comes to mind but this is purely for an API event. I am not sure if this would be the way to go since i have all the required data in Marketing Cloud. An idea would be to log the users who clicked one of the possible buttons via _Click data view into a data extension, including the buttonName field or link name to then split for the fitting reply mails. I just can't get around the part on how to listen to the click event and immediately react to it and send out the mailings.

I am sure that there is a way to achieve this goal since it shouldn't be to uncommon to immediately react to a contact's behabiour in a mailing :).

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: The only way I can think of, is to build a custom solution, using a Cloud Page Code Resource, which will be used to trigger an API call to a new journey or transactional send, while redirecting the contact to the actual URL

Comment: @LukasLunow, many thanks :).